# Deployer - deploy from git server to the same host (localhost)

Tags: php, git, deployment, localhost

I configured deployer on the local. I have also created remote git server. I am  going to deploy code to the same server as git server, so to its localhost.

The operation perform without errors and has successful info at its end, but the is no update of files then. When no localhost but the server hostname was specified in `deploy.php` file, the push process had been actually performed. Then I changed it to localhost and the problem appeared. How to achieve the deployment with localhost? This is the `deploy.php` file:

```
s@lokal:~/Dropbox/hosts$ cat deploy.php
<?php
namespace Deployer;

require 'recipe/common.php';

// Project name
set('application', 'hosts');

// Project repository
set('repository', 'git@gitadam.ga:trzczy/hosts.git');

// [Optional] Allocate tty for git clone. Default value is false.
set('git_tty', true); 

// Shared files/dirs between deploys 
set('shared_files', []);
set('shared_dirs', []);

// Writable dirs by web server 
set('writable_dirs', []);
set('allow_anonymous_stats', false);

// Hosts

localhost()
    ->user('deployer')
    ->set('deploy_path', '/var/www/html/hosts/production');

// Tasks

desc('Deploy your project');
task('deploy', [
    'deploy:info',
    'deploy:prepare',
    'deploy:lock',
    'deploy:release',
    'deploy:update_code',
    'deploy:shared',
    'deploy:writable',
    'deploy:vendors',
    'deploy:clear_paths',
    'deploy:symlink',
    'deploy:unlock',
    'cleanup',
    'success'
]);

// [Optional] If deploy fails automatically unlock.
after('deploy:failed', 'deploy:unlock');
s@lokal:~/Dropbox/hosts$
```